# How to use referencing? is it through using @id or need to declare global variable?

Tags: android, reference, global

this is part of my main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@id/infoname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:text="Hi Name"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome to Program"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

this is part of my editinfo.xml

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/infoname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="3 to 10 characters" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

from editing the id/infoname from edit text(for example input is MyName)
how could i do something like Hi MyName from the content main.xml
thanks :)

Comment: you should start with some tutorial in my opinion and the ask questions here. here is a good starting point http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial

Comment: XML is static. Do this in your Java class

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial, i need people answer/opinion as that's just the last thing i need to finish my basic program :( not a link :(

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to change the text property of your EditText programmatically?

In your Java file's onCreate:

`EditText yourEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.yourEditText); 

yourEditText.setText("MyName");`

You're getting a reference to your EditText object and setting the text property.

Comment: no, i mean my mainactivity will retrieve info from my editinfoactivity

Comment: so first i input "whatevername(@id/name)" in the edittext of "editinfoactivity.java(editinfo.xml)"

then i would want it to be reference in the"mainactivity.java(main.xml)"
that would go something like TextView.setText(@id/name)

but i don't know how..